# Suppress "Resolve Missing Assets" dialog when opening Embedded Smart Object from PhotoShop Script

Tags: javascript, photoshop-script

I need to programmatically suppress the "Resolve Missing Assets" dialog displayed by Photoshop when opening an Embedded Smart Object that contains broken library links. In my case, I don't care about missing links, and can't have the execution of my script blocked pending manual intervention to cancel the dialog.

I'm opening the Smart Object in Photoshop 2022 using JavaScript as follows (with additional filetype validation checks omitted for brevity):

```
app.displayDialogs = DialogModes.NO;

//...

if (layer.kind == LayerKind.SMARTOBJECT) {
    try {
        executeAction(stringIDToTypeID("placedLayerEditContents"), new ActionDescriptor(), DialogModes.NO);
        // <- dialog still shows here, script execution is blocked, and no exceptions to catch after dialog is closed
    } catch(e) {
        alert(e);
    }
}
```

The code works as expected, except that Photoshop seemingly ignores both the `DialogModes.NO` parameter, as well as the `displayDialogs` value set at the beginning. Wrapping the callsite in a try/catch doesn't help here, as whatever exception is being thrown when resolving linked assets is effectively swallowed by the Photoshop process and handled through the "relink" dialog before `executeAction` returns.

Querying for open dialogues to send a cancel or esc command from the script would be acceptable, but due to the blocking nature of this dialog, my script never has any knowledge of its existence until after it's closed manually (emitting an alert immediately after opening the Smart Object doesn't show until the dialog is closed).

Calling `app.runMenuItem` behaves no differently:

```
app.runMenuItem(stringIDToTypeID('placedLayerEditContents'));
```

Apart from [this thread describing the same problem](https://community.adobe.com/t5/photoshop-ecosystem-discussions/script-is-interrupted-by-dialog/m-p/11433392) from a couple of years ago that never fully got resolved, I've had no success finding an actual workaround for this.

I'm open to "creative" solutions that would mitigate this issue, if no clear cut method for suppressing this dialog is available, as long as it's non-destructive to the Smart Object contents (aka, no rasterizing/flattening). Asynchronously polling for the presence of the dialog window, or adding a listener when it is created both seem like reasonable workarounds, but my ps scripting experience is limited and I'm not sure how one would go about doing that.

Note that I'm dealing with *embedded* smart objects here, not *linked* smart objects, so there is no physical file backing the smart object prior to opening it through Photoshop (by double-clicking the smart object layer preview thumb, or selecting the "Edit Contents" item in the context menu when right clicking on the smart object layer).

Comment: Well... that's got me stumped too. I'd try the [Photoshop Eco System forums](https://community.adobe.com/t5/photoshop-ecosystem/ct-p/ct-photoshop)

Comment: Excellent suggestion, but nothing there either @GhoulFool

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a fix for suppressing  missing fonts. This will work as a get-around for the open dialogue on smart objects as well.
Code has been taken from [here](https://community.adobe.com/t5/photoshop-ecosystem-discussions/temporarily-suppress-missing-fonts-dialog/m-p/13172437)

```
var f = File.openDialog();
if (f)
{
  (d = new ActionDescriptor).putPath(stringIDToTypeID("target"), f);
  executeAction(stringIDToTypeID("open"), d, DialogModes.NO);
  // open your file now
}
```

Comment: While this does work, it assumes a target file exists. In my case, there is no file until the smart object is opened for editing. At that point, there is a temp file created, but by then it's too late as the missing assets prompt has already been shown. I've updated my post to clarify I'm dealing with _embedded_ smart objects, not _linked_ smart objects.